# How to capture specific info from CSV column in python

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I have a CSV file that has a table with information that I'd like to reference in another table. To give you a better perspective, I have the following example:

```
"ID","Name","Flavor"
"45fc754d-6a9b-4bde-b7ad-be91ae60f582","account1-test1","m1.medium"
"83dbc739-e436-4c9f-a561-c5b40a3a6da5","account3-test2","m1.tiny"
"ef68fcf3-f624-416d-a59b-bb8f1aa2a769","account1-test3","m1.medium"
```

I would like to add another column that references the Name column and pulls the customner name in one column and the rest of the info into another column, example:

```
"ID","Name","Flavor","Customer","Misc"
"45fc754d-6a9b-4bde-b7ad-be91ae60f582","account1-test1","m1.medium","account1","test1"
"83dbc739-e436-4c9f-a561-c5b40a3a6da5","account3-test2","m1.tiny","account3,"test2"
"ef68fcf3-f624-416d-a59b-bb8f1aa2a769","account1-test3","m1.medium","account1","test3"
```

The task here is to have a python script that opens the original CSV file, and creates a new CSV file with the added column. Any ideas? I've been having trouble parsing through the name column successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')
data[['Customer','Misc']] = data.Name.str.split("-",expand=True)
```

Now you can again save it to csv file by :

```
data.to_csv('another_file.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening your csv file with a `pandas DataFrame`. This can be done with:

```
df = pd.read_csv('input_data.csv')
```

If the `customer` and `misc` columns are part of another csv file you can load this with the same method as above (naming `df2`) and then append with the following:

```
df['Customer'] = df2['Customer']
```

You can then output the `DataFrame` as a csv file with the following:

```
df.to_csv('output_data_name.csv')
```